# how to troubleshoot AOSP make failure src not found error

Tags: repository, synchronization, android-source

I have read some of the content on Android source, and my goal is to build an image for the Note III from Sprint. My make fails with the following message at the top: "find: `src': No such file or directory". I started a script session of my make process, so if there is any other information I can provide, please let me know. I tried to download jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp branch for my device, and tried to build the full_toroplus-eng image. I think I have all the source from this branch. But I know very little about what I have. How do I validate my repo sync went smoothly? I get the following error at the end of my repo sync session:

```
9/platforms/android-12/arch-arm/usr/include/asm-generic/emergency-restart.h
9/platforms/android-12/arch-arm/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-
Aborting
Syncing work tree: 100% (348/348), done.  

prebuilts/ndk/: discarding 93 commits
error: prebuilts/ndk/: platform/prebuilts/ndk checkout 9283a93c7b03896d32a8e88c9322c827d4303652 
root@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY#
```

How do I find out more about this? How do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: The `find: 'src': No such file or directory".` message is expected and most likely had nothing to do with your failing build. The actual cause of the failure is probably closer to the end of the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I have all the source from this branch. But I know very little about what I have. How do I validate my repo sync went smoothly?

If Repo terminated with a zero exit code you're good to go.

> I get the following error at the end of my repo sync session:
>
> prebuilts/ndk/: discarding 93 commits
>   error: prebuilts/ndk/: platform/prebuilts/ndk checkout 9283a93c7b03896d32a8e88c9322c827d4303652

If memory serves me right, this means that the prebuilts/ndk directory is dirty (i.e. contains modified files) and thus prevents checking out a new commit. Running `git status` will tell you what's up.

Comment: I think you are right. Does this validate it?         root@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY# ~/bin/repo status | grep /ndk
project prebuilts/ndk/                          (*** NO BRANCH ***)
root@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY#

Comment: No, the output of that command doesn't prove that the git doesn't have any dirty files. Run `git status` in that git. And please don't build as root.

Comment: Magnus - Thanks, your comment helped a lot. Just so we know the fix, I had to delete the /prebuilts directory, and sync again. Sync worked without error this time. I also changed to another version. Kitkat is just too new. Jelly Bean seems to be more functional right now. Re: your comment on not building as root. Ok sure. I guess I'll use sudo to issue commands. Just so I know, what can happen if I do stay in root?

Comment: I am the proud owner of a new system image:-) Install system fs image: out/target/product/toroplus/system.img. Thanks Magnus.

Comment: Don't use sudo either. Build using your regular user account. There's absolutely no need to build as root and screw ups can have greater consequences since root is a privileged user.

Comment: Magnus, I appreciate that. After having a chance to think about it, I realized why it is a concern. For the purpose of my system image, it is only for a proof of concept, and I will role it back to good old Cyanogenmod. But I was considering to keep the image, if it worked for me. I am glad you pointed this out. Thank you so much. Frankly, building a stable build env was time consuming, and I really don't want to fiddle with it. But security is very important, and I'll definitely move to a user environment. After I back up the VM off course:-)